# Overloading methods without duplicating content

Tags: c#

```
private bool CheckNotification(Dictionary<string, DateTime> dict, string key, int duration)
{
    return !dict.ContainsKey(key) || (DateTime.Now - dict[key]).TotalSeconds >= duration;
}

private bool CheckNotification(Dictionary<int, DateTime> dict, int key, int duration)
{
    return !dict.ContainsKey(key) || (DateTime.Now - dict[key]).TotalSeconds >= duration;
}
```

I have the method above overloaded for different dictionary key types - is there a way I can do this without having the duplicated code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it generic:

```
private bool CheckNotification<T>(Dictionary<T, DateTime> dict, T key, int duration)
{
    return !dict.ContainsKey(key) || (DateTime.Now - dict[key]).TotalSeconds >= duration;
}
```